# Windows Server 2012 R2 in Virtualbox error

Tags: windows, virtualbox

I'm trying to install Windows Server 2012 R2 on Virtualbox but I get this error all the time:

[image]

```
Proccessor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU
System type: 64-bit
ISO file: en_windows_server_2012_x64_dvd_915478.iso
```

I've tried many things and had no result, I tried on another computer but got the same error.

When creating a new VirtualMachine I used `"Windows > Other Windows"` and created a new VDI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common problem. You have to activate virtualization in your bios. If doesn't matter if you have a 64 bits CPU if you don't have the virtualization activated. This is [an example](http://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/enable-virtualization-in-the-bios/).

Comment: I've just checked the `"Virtualization Technology"` in my BIOS but I still have the error.

Comment: Wait a second, it does work. I now have the option: "Windows 2010 (64bit)" when creating a new virtual machine. Thanks! I can finally study my exam

Comment: Glad to have helped you.